# SetDefaultValueSql() in EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a solution for auditable entities that works well with EF Core 3.1 and .Net 5.0. But I need to make it work in an old project with EF Core 2.2. The problem is that *SetDefaultValueSql()* is only available in 3.1 and 5.0.

I cannot find any solution to replace `property.SetDefaultValueSql("getdate()");` for the old 2.2 version.

My code:

```
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(t => t.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AuditableEntity)))
)
{
    foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => AuditProperties.Contains(p.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
                     && (p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) || p.ClrType == typeof(DateTimeOffset)))
    )
    {
        property.SetDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set the Default SQL Value same way in EF Core 2.2?

Comment: You can read the source code to see how it is implemented in later versions https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/f54b9dcd189c91fc4b01b79c9387d23095819a8f/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalPropertyBuilderExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
property.HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
```

I test it in ef core 2.x, about more infomation, you can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#default-values).

Comment: No, it does not work so. I have tried HasDefaultValueSql() already. It does not work in my code.

Comment: The variable property has hier the type `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IMutableProperty` and it does not have both methods in 2.2 (`SetDefaultValueSql` and `HasDefaultValueSql`)